# How to clear shopping cart automatically after a certain period in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I have created a e-commerece site. my problm is that i want to clear shopping cart by itself after a certion period if user left the site after adding the items in cart either he is logged in or not.

My Global.ascx code is:

```
void Profile_OnMigrateAnonymous(object sender, ProfileMigrateEventArgs e)
{
    ProfileCommon anonymousProfile = Profile.GetProfile(e.AnonymousID);
    if (anonymousProfile.SCart != null)
    {
        if (Profile.SCart == null)
            Profile.SCart = new ShoppingCartExample.Cart();

        Profile.SCart.Items.AddRange(anonymousProfile.SCart.Items);

        anonymousProfile.SCart = null;
    }

    ProfileManager.DeleteProfile(e.AnonymousID);
    AnonymousIdentificationModule.ClearAnonymousIdentifier();
}
```

but i dont know that how to do this . please help me. 
Thanks.

Comment: Suggest you use session to store the "shopping cart"

Comment: And set the "Timeout" of the session

Comment: user can purchase item even if he is not logged in. it's a requirement of client.

Comment: Don't know what you mean, is that the requirement said that users can purchase items even the user isn't logged in?

Comment: If so, you can store the cart in the session, "session" isn't only for storing user login infos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [System.Web.Caching.Cache](http://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/4y13wyk9%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) to cache the shoping cart. You can use Absolute or Sliding expiration to control the time period the cart is in cache.

With cache, just retrieve the cart, if return null, cache has expired (means cleared cart).

Comment: This is not entirely appropriate, as the cache is available to all users - you'd need to key the insert appropriately.  Session would seem a more sensible choice, as it is per user and automatically expires.

Comment: Of course you need a unique key for every cart you have in cache.

Comment: I guess my point is why store user specific info using a mechanism that is potentially accessible by all users (if there was a coding error) when there is a built in mechanism whereby the information can *only* be accessed by the associated user.

Comment: Because if session can not be Inproc you don't have event to control when cart is cleared to execute code. In cache you can configure a callback when data expires. Is very usefull.

Answer (score 0):

Profile is used to persist data across sessions or across logins.

You should use session to store this user's cart information - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178581.aspx.

Session is a temporary information store that exists for a certain period.  As the sessions automatically expire; the shopping cart would get cleared after a period.

Sessions can store any piece of information that you need and are in no way limited to login or authentication information.

```
Session["ShoppingCart"] = new ShoppingCartExample.Cart();
```